# Why does async + await return AsyncFunction?

Tags: javascript, typescript

### code

```
const config = async () => {
  return await import("../test");
}

console.log(config);
```

../test

```js
export const config = {
  value1: 1,
  value1: 2,
};
```

I want `config` in ../test but this returns `[AsyncFunction: config]`.

Comment: `const config = await import("../test")` will return what you want. `async (...) => { ... }` is literally the definition of an async function.

Answer (score 2):

`async () => {}` is a function declaration. So you assigned `config` to a function.

You have to call that function, and `await` the result, in order to get the value you want.

```
console.log(await config());
```

---

But are you sure you want a dynamic import here?

Because this should do the same thing without any headaches at all.

```
import { config } from "../test";
```

Comment: Thanks. Buit I got this error `Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'esnext' or 'system', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.` I think I can't use await.

Comment: To use [_top level_ `await`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#top-level-await) you have to change your tsconfig as instructed by that error message. But you should be able to use `await` from inside any function without making those changes.

Comment: I would like to use a dynamic import